# Is the concept of Chalit Chart mentioned in our scriptures related to astrology?

Tags: scripture, astrology, navagraha

We know that there is a concept of Chalit Chart in Astrology where a planet changes its house and gives the results according to the new house and sometimes, gives results of both the houses. But the aspects of the planet (The houses aspects) in any case are to be seen with the Lagna Chart.

As far as I know,
There are 3 types of Chalit Charts:

1. Sam Vibhaajan Paddhati
2. Shripati Paddhati
3. Cuspal Paddhati

So my question is as follows:

Is this concept of Bhava Chalit authentic and mentioned in the scriptures that are made for astrology like that of Parashara muni, etc., or was it invented recently?